# Raspberry Pi background program runs but doesnt work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

SOLVED: For some reason making CRON run a bash script that runs the python script solved the problem.

I have a python script "temperature.py" which is an infinite loop that checks values from a GPIO pin, adds the values to a file which it uploads to google drive with "gdrive" and sometimes sends a mail using smtp. The script works perfectly if i run it from the SSH terminal ($ sudo python temperature.py) but it doesn't work at startup like i would want it to.
I'm using raspbian wheezy.

What I've done:

in /etc/rc.local:

```
#...
#...

sleep 10
python /home/pi/temperature.py&
exit 0
```

the pi boots normally and after i login using SSH and write:

```
...$ps aux
```

i get:

```
...
root   2357   1.4   1.9   10556   8836 ?    S 21:11   0:12 python /home/pi/temperature.py
...
```

so I'm guessing it is running and it uses 1.4% CPU which is very little but almost all other processes use 0.0%. Since the program probably
It doesnt do anything however... my google drive is empty...

**So it works if i run it from terminal as background but not if i run it from rc.local...**

What I'm guessing :

1. it lacks some permission?
2. it must be something with rc.local... since it works perfectly from terminal
   The result of

   ...$ls -l temperature.py 
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1927 Dec 12 21:10 temperature.py 
   ...$ls -l /etc/rc.local
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 373 Dec 12 20:54 /etc/rc.local

I have tried staring it using cron ($sudo crontab -e) but it didn't work either.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm missing something obvious but since I'm very new to raspberry pi and linux stuff I can't find it on google.

The script temperature.py

```
#Made by Matthew Kirk
# Licensed under MIT License, see
# http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/freshers/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/LICENSE
#Adapted by me

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess
import os
import commands
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

print 'TEMPERATURE LOGGER - M'
print ' '
#MAILER SETUP
to = '****@gmail.com'
gmail_user = '****@gmail.com'
gmail_password = '*****'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

#TEMP LOGGER GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN)

while True:
    print 'fail'
    if GPIO.input(7):
            break

while GPIO.input(7):
    pass

waitTime = 60

tempTreshold = 50
logFile  = "/home/pi/tDat.csv"
while True:
    dataFile = open(logFile,"a")
    time_1 = time.time()
    tFile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-011582ac5dff/w1_slave")
    text = tFile.read();
    tFile.close();

    tData = text.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
    temp = float(tData[2:])
    temp = temp/1000
    timeStamp = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    dataFile.write(str(temp)+","+ timeStamp+ "\n")
    dataFile.close()
    file_ID = commands.getoutput('drive list | tail -n +2 | head -1 | awk \'{print $1;}\' ')
    cmd = 'drive delete --id '+file_ID
    os.system( cmd )
    cmd = 'drive upload --file '+logFile
    os.system( cmd )
 # MAIL IF TEMP TOO LOW
    if temp < tempTreshold:
            smtpserver.ehlo()
            smtpserver.starttls()
            smtpserver.ehlo()
            smtpserver.login(gmail_user,gmail_password)
            msg = MIMEText('The temperature in Branten, {}C, is below {} degrees C!!!'.format(temp,tempTreshold)+'\n'+'Recorded$
            msg['Subject'] = 'Branten Temperature Warning'
            msg['From'] = gmail_user
            msg['To'] = to
            smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user,[to],msg.as_string())
            smtpserver.quit()

    sys.exit()
```

and the CRON:

```
* * * * * python /home/pi/temperature.py
```

Comment: Can you post the python script?

Comment: Where is the file the script writes to? Did you use an absolute path?

Comment: the file is in the same folder as the script  "/home/pi", no i did not use absolute, should i?

Comment: @elParaguayo: i added the script code

Comment: You'll need an absolute path for the file as rc.local runs from your "/" directory.

Comment: thank you, that was one problem, now it writes the data successfully and sends emails but still wont upload to gdrive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider revising your code to not use an infinate loop.

Read about Linux CRON jobs.  CRON is a service that will execute your program or script on a schedule (properly). EDIT: it is installed by default on most linux distros including Rasbian.

[Some good examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: I tried CRON jobs previously but it did not work either :( I had modified it to not be an infinite loop and CRON to call it every hour.

Comment: I must admit cron can be frustrating.  In your case, i would run 'sudo crontab -e' so when you create your cron job it runs as root.  I had the same issue not understanding why the DHT sensor would not read although I was able to do it in the console without root.  Just make your crontab as root and see what happens!  Also double check that the time setting is correct as it can be confusing

Comment: sudo crontab -e is what i used, with : 0 * * * * /home/pi/temperature.py and @reboot /home/pi/temperature.py

Comment: if you want it to run every minute you should do */1 * * * * ...  and also i suggest creating a bash script that simply runs the python script so the cron tab does not require arguments

Comment: Okay, i made some tests, now CRON starts my script once a minute (it shows up on ps aux with 90% CPU) but it still doesnt upload the file.

Comment: remove the loop because there is no need for it.  make sure you have ssl enabled and have the most recent version of openssl. run sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion to make a bash script that runs the python script solved the problem for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nohup helps?

```
nohup python /home/pi/temperature.py&
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't :( (tested)